# Getting data from HTML chart

Tags: html, charts, xmlhttprequest

I have been attempting to extract data from the following site: https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/activeaddresses-btc-eth-ltc.html

In a frustrating turn of events, there is no download button and I have been having a hard time finding some means of accessing the data contained in that chart. I have attempted to "inspect" the chart and then look to the Network tab to no avail. I would greatly appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Comment: The chart's data appears to be in the source code. Something [like this](https://pastebin.com/0Jhv13EK).

Comment: Ok! How did you find that? Thanks!

Comment: By [viewing the source code](https://www.wikihow.com/View-Source-Code) for that page. The data can be found in a JavaScript array.

Comment: You are thebomb.com! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this script to extract the Ethereum as well as Bitcoin data. You can modify it for others. The code downloads the data and applies cubicspline interpolation to any missing values. You may skip the interpolation part if you do not need that part:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import numpy as np

def parse_strlist(sl):
    clean = re.sub("[\[\],\s]","",sl)
    splitted = re.split("[\'\"]",clean)
    values_only = [s for s in splitted if s != '']
    return values_only

def fetch_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    for script in scripts:
        if 'd = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("container")' in script.text:
            StrList = script.text
            StrList = '[[' + StrList.split('[[')[-1]
            StrList = StrList.split(']]')[0] +']]'
            StrList = StrList.replace("new Date(", '').replace(')','')
            dataList = parse_strlist(StrList)
            return dataList

def create_dataframe(dataList):
    date = []
    value = []
    for each in dataList:
        if (dataList.index(each) % 2) == 0:
            date.append(each)
        else:
            value.append(each)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date, value)), columns=["Date","Price"])
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'], errors='coerce')
    return df

def interpolate_data(df):
    df = df.resample('D').mean()
    x = np.arange(len(df))
    y = df['Price'].values
    mask = np.isfinite(y)
    cs = CubicSpline(x[mask], y[mask])
    df['Price'] = cs(x)
    return df

# URLs for Bitcoin and Ethereum
btc_url = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-price.html#alltime'
eth_url = 'https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/ethereum-price.html#alltime'

# Fetch and process data
btc_data_list = fetch_data(btc_url)
eth_data_list = fetch_data(eth_url)

btc_df = create_dataframe(btc_data_list)
eth_df = create_dataframe(eth_data_list)

btc_df_interpolated = interpolate_data(btc_df)
eth_df_interpolated = interpolate_data(eth_df)

# Save to CSV
btc_df_interpolated.to_csv('bitcoin_prices.csv')
eth_df_interpolated.to_csv('ethereum_prices.csv')
```